# What is the motivation behind $\tau=\mu \frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}y}$ for Newtonian fluid?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

Where does the motivation come from? $\tau$ is the shear stress, $u$ is the velocity and $\mu$ is the shear viscosity.

EDIT: Since I wrote the question on phone I wasn't clear enough about what I was actually wondering about (see comments below); thus let me clarify.

I was simply wondering where did the derivative term come from and not why the expression is linear in the derivative term or why it is the first derivative and not e.g. the second and so on.

The diagram in the answer I accepted shows exactly how the gradient comes into the picture.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The motivation comes from applying the [no-slip boundary condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-slip_condition) on a fluid flow. This is probably easier to understand pictorially,

[image]

The fluid at the top travels at $u$ while the fluid at the bottom does not move, hence the gradient $\partial u/\partial y>0$. In order to properly model fluid flows, this needs to be accounted for in the Navier-Stokes equations; it is called $\tau$ for "simplifying" the equations.

Comment: This was what I was looking for, ie that there exists a nonzero velocity gradient. The picture was sufficient to make me recall everything from few years back. Thanks

Comment: Why not $\tau = \mu (\frac{du}{dx})^2 $?  The no-slip boundary condition has little to do with motivating the use of $\tau = \mu \frac{d u}{d x}$.  I recommend reading "Vectors, Tensors and the Basic Equations of Fluid Mechanics" by Rutherford Aris.

Comment: @SimpleLikeAnEgg, a small column of fluid undergoes a shear strain $\frac{\Delta x}{\Delta y}$ in a time $\Delta t$, so the rate of shear strain is $\frac{\Delta x }{ \Delta t \Delta y} \to \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$. In general, one would expect $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = f(\tau)$, and a linear relationship is the simplest to consider. Sir Newton wasn't thinking about wet cornstarch when he wrote the equation.

Comment: @lionelbrits I don't think it was clear to everyone, even the author of the question, as to what he asked.  At least to me, I think your comment here is a far better answer as to the motivation of $\tau = \mu \frac{du}{dx}$ than the answer you gave or the accepted answer, neither of which give any real motivation.  However, I'm still not convinced that "in general, one would expect $\frac{du}{dy} = f(\tau)$" is a justifiable motivation.

Comment: From Kundu & Cohen 3rd edition, page 7: ***Experiments** show that the magnitude of the shear stress $\tau$ along a surface such as $AB$ is, to a good approximation, related to the velocity gradient by the **linear** relation $\tau=\mu(du/dy)$, which is called Newton's law of friction.* (emphasis mine). Without the no-slip condition, viscous effects can be ignored, Prandtl showed this in 1905, good to know that Aris ignores this fact and Kundu doesn't, perhaps *you* should update your library?

Comment: @KyleKanos  Nice. You didn't even understand what you read.  "Without the no-slip condition, viscous effects can be ignored, Prandtl showed this in 1905."  There are plenty of flows without no-slip boundaries where viscous effects cannot be ignored.  All that Prandtl showed is that *incompressible* flows that are initially irrotational will remain irrotational in the absence of no-slip boundaries.  Alternatively, for compressible flows this is not the case at all as baroclinic generation of vorticity can occur.  No-slip boundaries are not a motivation for $\tau = \mu \frac{du}{dy}$.

Comment: @KyleKanos "Experiments show that the magnitude of the shear stress τ along a surface such as AB is, to a good approximation, related to the velocity gradient by the linear relation τ=μ(du/dy)"  Glad to see you've finally found one of the motivations for $\tau = \mu \frac{du}{dy}$

Comment: @KyleKanos  In fact, your profile picture of a super nova is a perfect example of a compressible turbulent flow without no-slip boundaries where viscous effects obviously cannot be ignored.  Keep reading.

Comment: @SimpleLikeAnEgg: AFAIK, you cannot get the linear relationship without a static boundary; this requires the no-slip condition. Prandtl's 1905 paper developed the concept of the boundary layer in which viscous forces are applied on the no-slip boundary and ignored at some height above this layer. I don't know that incompressibility really had anything to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

It's a tautology. The [viscosity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viscosity) is the proportionality constant for Newtonian fluids. We can imagine a small column of fluid that undergoes a shear strain $\frac{\Delta x}{\Delta y}$ in a time $\Delta t$, so the rate of shear strain is $\frac{\Delta x}{\Delta t \Delta y} \to \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$ .

In general, one would expect a layer of fluid subjected to some stress (force) to accelerate until it the force acted on it is balanced by the drag force it experiences from the layer underneath it. Then we reach some sort of steady state velocity distribution. From this we would characterize the velocity distribution by some function of stress and velocity:

$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=f(\tau, u)$.

Now, in studying fluids like water, one learns that at very low velocities (actually, low Reynolds numbers) that drag force is *linear* with velocity, i.e., $f_d = - b\, v$. In this case, one could argue that in the (inertial) rest frame of the layer of fluid, it is only the relative velocities of the fluid layers that enter the force equation, so

$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=f(\tau)$.

Furthermore, if the drag force is linear with velocity, i.e., $f_d = - b\, v_\mathrm{rel}$, then the force on a layer of fluid must be equal to the net force acting on it from the layer above or the layer beneath, i.e., $f_d = - b\, v_\mathrm{rel} = -b \frac{\Delta v}{\Delta y} \Delta y$. Note that the mass of the layer is proportional to $\Delta y$, so we would expect it to drop out once we scale our equations appropriately.

I think the point is that Sir Newton wasn't thinking about wet cornstarch when he wrote the equation. For non-Newtonian fluids, the proportionality constant changes with $\frac{du}{dy}$.

See [this chart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aViscous_regimes_chart.png) for example.

Comment: Why not $\tau = \mu \frac{d^2u}{dx^2}$ or $\tau = \mu \frac{d^3u}{dx^3}$?

Comment: Because then it wouldn't be Newtonian?

Comment: I think this answer is correct, but assumes a very strict interpretation of the OP's question. Perhaps the OP meant why is it *reasonable* to assume that some fluids might obey this model.

Comment: Ok, I'm much more satisfied with my answer now.